# flutter_local_notifications issue I'm facing when I run my partner app

Tags: flutter

flutter_local_notifications issue I'm facing, when I'm going to run my partner app.

```
    C:\src\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\flutter_local_notifications-9.9.1\android\src\main\java\com\dexterous\flutterlocalnotifications\FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.java:1554: error: cannot find symbol
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU) {
                                                        ^
      symbol:   variable TIRAMISU
      location: class VERSION_CODES
    C:\src\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\flutter_local_notifications-9.9.1\android\src\main\java\com\dexterous\flutterlocalnotifications\FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.java:1555: error: cannot find symbol
          String permission = Manifest.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS;
                                                 ^
      symbol:   variable POST_NOTIFICATIONS
      location: class permission
    2 errors
    
    FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
    
    * What went wrong:
    Execution failed for task ':flutter_local_notifications:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
    > Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
    
    * Try:
    Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
    
    * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
    
    BUILD FAILED in 3m 20s
    Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Maybe problem with permissions. Research android setup: https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications#-android-setup